# How to parse object inside json

Tags: php, json

I want to show json object as var i'm trying to upload files on anonfiles using api but after uploading file it shows result in json format. so i want get particular object inside json here is my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$url = sprintf('https://api.anonfiles.com/upload', $token);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
'file' => curl_file_create(
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
$_FILES['file']['type'],
$_FILES['file']['name']
),
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$json = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($json);

if (is_object($result) && $result->status) {
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access a particular object inside JSON, you are already doing it with the `$result->status`.
After you `json_decode` your JSON data, simply use `$result->[the JSON NODE]` to which data that you require.

Comment: when i follow your  your example there is an error while uploading file. Here  is the nodes ```"{"status":true,"data":{"file":{"url":{"full":"https://anonfile.com/v5W9Y6v3o6/advent_jpg","short":"https://anonfile.com/v5W9Y6v3o6"},
"metadata":{"id":"v5W9Y6v3o6","name":"advent.jpg","size":{"bytes":15934,"readable":"15.93 KB"}}}}}

Comment: What is it that you want exactly?

Comment: i want to get only file url inside object

Comment: if thats the case, you have to traverse all the relevant node too, from the root. like this, `$result->data->file->url->full`

Comment: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string